# Reusing Knockout Observables on Different HTML Elements

Tags: knockout.js

I have a page that has a text box input. I add elements to this text box and using a Knockout obervable array, display the contents . 
Now I need to add another textbox , create another collection and   display it.
Do I need to create another observable array (and another method to add elements to the array) ?
Is there any way I can reuse the code ? If not , I might have to create as many observable arrays as the collections I need to display.

```
 dataStore: ko.observableArray([]),        
        nameToAdd: ko.observable(''),
        add: function () {
            var val = this.nameToAdd();
            var pos = this.dataStore.indexOf(val.trim());
            if (pos === - 1 && this.nameToAdd() .length > 0 && this.nameToAdd() .trim() != '') {
                this.dataStore.push(val);
                this.nameToAdd('');
                $('#txtSetInput') .focus();
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mayurarora/ZtL8t/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reuse of logic comes from using constructor functions to represent your view models, not just plain JavaScript objects. Run through the [KnockoutJS tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/), and if you are low on time at least do [the one on collections](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections).

For your scenario, you could go along these lines:

```
var ItemViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable("");

};

var MainViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.dataStore = ko.observableArray([new ItemViewModel()]);    

    self.addItem = function(item) {
        self.dataStore.push(new ItemViewModel());
    };

    self.clear = function(item) {
        self.dataStore.remove(item);
    };
};

$(function () {
    var viewModel = new MainViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

See also [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtL8t/4/).